# How can I add drop shadows to all 4 corners of a box using CSS?

Tags: css, dropshadow

I am trying to apply a drop shadow to all four corners of a box using just CSS so it looks like all 4 corners are just barely lifted off the page, like on this site: http://www.leighannphotography.com/#home/

So far, I only know how to add shadows to just 2 corners using before and after pseudo elements and classes. Is there a way to add shadows to all four corners with CSS? I prefer not to use an image for the shadows since there is already a slider on the page, and I don't want the page to load any slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my work here

http://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/voEfG

So basically the shadow itself already consume 100px of height. So make sure the content you will put inside `<div class="content">` has minimum height around 110px

Comment: Okay, so your method is to create an empty div above and below the div I want to add the shadows to. Thanks so much Bobby- this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: you're welcome. do contact me if you have more questions. and please vote my answer.